# Shopify: Why the dynamic checkout button is always disabled?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I followed this guide to add a dynamic checkout button into the slider cart, but it's always disabled. I searched on google and stackoverflow as well as shopify community, but no answer.

please check this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/shryzw  When clicking the add to cart button, then the slider cart container will be displayed to the right side. I just simply copied the following codes to the slider cart, not sure why the dynamic checkout button is always disabled in the slider cart, but it works on the product page. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
{% form 'product', product %}
  {{ form | payment_button }}
{% endform %}
```

Comment: I found I use the incorrect code, but my purpose is add a paypal express button in the slider cart.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. Just replace the code to this:

```
{% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
      <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
        {{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```